# Avoiding sudo to root with an alias, is it possible?

Tags: sudo, best-practices

I've developed a bad habit of constantly sudoing to root. I was wondering if its possible to create an alias that prevents straight sudo but allows sudo -u. Or possibly echoes a warning when using sudo?

Comment: Why not just fix your bad habits?

Answer (score 4):

This is a people problem, but...

By default sudo gives a warning when asking for your password ("with great power comes great responsibility etc etc")

You can use a custom sudo lecture file to setup a custom warning.

In `/etc/sudoers`

`Defaults lecture_file=/home/user/lecture lecture=always`